# How do I simplify the rational expression $\frac1{2b} + \frac b2$

Tags: fractions

So the expression is:

$$\frac1{2b} + \frac b2$$

Apparently the answer is $\frac{1 + b^2}{ 2b}$.

I came up with $2b$ by multiplying the first fraction by $2$ and the second fraction by $2b.$

I got:
$$\frac{2+ 2b^2}{2(2b)}$$ which simplifies to $\frac{2b^2}{2b}$ which is where I got $2b$ from.  Can someone help me with this problem and the LCD?

Comment: Khan academy is your friend-https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/fraction-arithmetic/arith-review-common-denominators/v/finding-common-denominators

Comment: A lot of your notation is ambiguous, but I'm trying to put it into correct notation. Please check my edits. I'm particularly concerned about the expression after "I got:..," because your error is either in this step, or the very next step.

Comment: How did you get ${2b^2\over2b}$ from ${2+2b^2\over2(2b)}$? It looks like you divided the denominator by $2$, but subtracted $2$ from the numerator. Or did you perhaps drop the $1$ term after dividing the numerator by $2$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have

$$
\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{b}{2}
$$

the LCD of the denominators is $2b$; therefore, the first fraction can be left alone, and the second fraction multiplied by $b/b$ to yield

$$
\frac{1}{2b}+\frac{b^2}{2b}
$$

which can then be combined to obtain

$$
\frac{1+b^2}{2b}
$$

---

It seemed to me, incidentally, that you obtained

$$
\frac{2+2b^2}{2(2b)}
$$

which wants only division by $2/2$ to get

$$
\frac{1+b^2}{2b}
$$

as above.  As a side note, I would say that writing out fractions "in-line" as opposed to "stacked" (as it were) makes it potentially confusing just exactly where the numerators and denominators begin and end.  I don't know if you're doing that as you work out the problem, but if you are, it might lead to errors.

Comment: Oh my gosh it makes so much sense now!  I can see it was just silly mistakes that led me astray.  Thank you so much!! Your help is greatly appreciated.